# Windows Azure - Worker role - detect environment

Tags: c#, windows, asp.net-mvc-2, azure

Anyone know of a way to determine if a worker role is running in the production or staging environment?

My worker role sends out daily email summaries of activities but if I have code in staging the email gets duplicated because I have two workers running.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

RoleEnvironment static class is available to find out current deploymentId.  Using current deploymentId you can query the Diagnostics Management API to find out the type of a deployment 0 or 1. I believe "0" is production and "1" is Staging.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Awesome I'll give that a try!

Comment: Sorry bur Wrong it doesn't work! In the deployementId you will get something like this : 2911092443f24494883914df12ca5936