# Is there a way to know in what environment my webrole runs?

Tags: azure, azure-configuration

I am working on azure webrole, and in one of my application which is console application, I want to know in which enviroment my webrole running?

I.e staging / production environment.

Is there any dll available to get this idea? I am looking for the solution available with
dll provided by azure, not the REST API?

**I want to do without the user of CERTIFICATE**

Answer (score 1):

check back [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4672885/windows-azure-worker-role-detect-environment).

There is no other way (that I know) to get the environment type.

Answer (score 0):

Another good approach is given [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sa/windowsazuredevelopment/thread/27aa21af-a7d7-424f-9fcc-107dbeaf53ee)

> ...you can check your application url, if its what your service name is then its production, othrwise if its some random guid then staging.