# How to check staging or production by IIS setting from EXE on Azure

Tags: azure

I am looking for some solution to detect whether a webrole is running in staging or production on the Windows Azure platform by Exe running in background **without certificates**.

Does anyone know if there are any differences between staging & Production IIS setting? I am looking for differences that will remain after performing a VIP swap.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Windows Azure - Worker role - detect environment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4672885/windows-azure-worker-role-detect-environment)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to that specific question would be "NO".

The idea of Production and Staging environment is that they are literally the same, so you can really test your deployment in native Azure enviornment. The only difference by staging and production is the subdomain of cloudapp.net. For production, you have your service name (http://myservice.cloudapp.net/) while for staging you have dynamically generated guid for subdomain.

You may quickly review the following resources, all mentioning staging vs production, detect, etc:

- [from msdn forums](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/windowsazuremanagement/thread/dcf5d412-94d1-4937-92f3-af6daf7abdce)
- [similar question on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4328462/staging-or-production-instance)

You also can't rely on determing the domain address from within the role instance itself, as the site bindings for the web role are with blank host header.